# Error en Formulario PHP

Tags: php

tengo una pequeña duda he estado trabajando en un formulario. La cuestion esta en que cuando cargo la pagina me evalua todo y me muestra error pero cuando ingreso datos me muestra los datos que solicito sin errores.

```
<?php
    include "mysqlcon.php";
    $con = connect();
    $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
    $datos = $_POST['datos'];
    if ($datos <> 0) {
        if ($opcion == 1) {
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id LIKE $datos"; 
        }
        if($opcion == 2){
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE telefono LIKE $datos"; 
        }
        $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
        $contador = 0;
        while ($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ $contador++;?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $contador; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $misdatos["id"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $misdatos["telefono"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $misdatos["nombre"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $misdatos["contacto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $misdatos["nombre"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
    }
}?>
```

No se en que estoy fallando, ya probe con un while pero no me funciono.

Comment: Puedes ser mas específico en el tipo de error que te muestra?

Comment: Claro, me dice _"Undefined index: opcion in C:\xampp\htdocs\suana\registros\index.php on line 49"_ ese es el error que me muestra. "opcion" es un dato que recojo de una lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te da, debido a que al entrar a la página $_POST['opcion'] & $_POST['datos'] no se encuentran definidos. (Esto es por que se envían a través del formulario)

Para ello te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente.

Agregar una verificación para saber si los valores vienen desde el formulario

```
<?php
    include "mysqlcon.php";
    $con = connect();
    if(isset($_POST['opcion']) && isset($_POST['datos']))
    {
       $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
       $datos = $_POST['datos'];
       if ($datos <> 0) {
       if ($opcion == 1) {
         $consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id LIKE $datos"; 
       }
       if($opcion == 2){
          $consulta = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE telefono LIKE $datos"; 
       }
       $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
       $contador = 0;
       while ($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ $contador++;?>

       <tr>
          <th scope="row"><?php echo $contador; ?></th>
          <td><?php echo $misdatos["id"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $misdatos["telefono"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $misdatos["nombre"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $misdatos["contacto"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $misdatos["nombre"]; ?></td>
       </tr>
    <?php }
    }
    } // Fin de la condición IF
 else{
     //Código adicional para cuando las variables POST no tengan valor
 }
?>
```

Toma en cuenta que cuando las variables POST no estén definidas, por tu código la página te la puede mostrar en blanco, para ello debes imprimir la tabla dentro del ELSE, con los valores que consideres

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, Dure toda la mañana buscando la solucion, Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes simplificar tu codigo escribiendo todo en una solo etiqueta PHP:

```
 echo " <tr>
               <th scope='row'>".$contador."</th>
               <td>".$misdatos['id']."</td>
               <td>".$misdatos['telefono']."</td>
               <td>".$misdatos['nombre']."</td>
               <td>".$misdatos['contacto']."</td>
               <td>".$misdatos['nombre']."</td>
             </tr>";
```

Luego si te dice que el index opcion es indefindo es porque no esta llegando desde la vista donde haces el submit:
para debuguear puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
 $opcion = $_POST['opcion'];
 $datos = $_POST['datos'];
 var_dump($opcion);exit(); // esto te mostrara lo que tiene esa variable
```